# Backup and restore ZFS filesystem incrementally over webdav or ftps

Tags: backup, zfs, webdav, ftps

On my main server, I use ZFS as a file system. So far I send incremental zfs snapshots to a backup machine which also has zfs available as a file system.

Unfortunately, the backup server has a headcrash, so I would like to move the backup system to a cloud drive which I can access via webdav/ftps.

How can I send incremental snapshots to/from such a backup drive? Can I somehow create a zpool which stores its data via webdav or ftps?

Thanks a lot for your ideas!